# TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined this error always retrun

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to set a text filter to add search functionality in my react and get error Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined 
here code that may be of help

My Code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import CardList from "./cardList";
import { robots } from "./robots";
import SearchBox from "./searchBox";

   class App extends Component {
   constructor() {
    super();
          this.state = {
         robots: robots,
          searchfield:''
        }
       }

   onSearchChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({searchfield: event.target.value})
      }

  render() {
    const filteredRobots = this.state.robots.filter(robots =>{
        return robots.mame.toLowerCase().includes(
    this.state.searchfield.toLowerCase());

     });
     return (
      <div className="tc">
         <h1> robots Friends </h1>
        <SearchBox searchChange={this.onSearchChange}/>
        <CardList robots={filteredRobots}/>
       </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: The problem might be here:

`robots.mame.toLowerCase().includes(...)`

Is the property you're trying to access on `robots` called `mame` or `name`?

Answer (score 0):

Lint included CSS files.
I found an empty property `border-color:;` to cause this kind of message.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57772350/1235724