# Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined - REACT - FIRESTORE

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I'm a bit new to React and Firestore and already trying to figure out what is happening for a couple of hours. I Try to make my filter function working with data which I receive from Firestore in APP.js. I pass the data {tasks, searchTerm} to DASHBOARD component. The filter worked before when using state and props, but after replacing the hard-coded data in state with firestore data, it doesn't work anymore and I get the following error when filtering the array in the DASHBOARD component:
**Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined**

I've tried to send the data without any filtering directly to TASKS.js and this is working correctly (all the tasks are shown). But as soon as I pass newArray to , it doesn't work anymore.

Also, when logging task.title in tasks.filter function in the DASHBOARD component, it shows all the data (with a little delay because the data is coming from Firestore)

APP.JS -

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Dashboard from './Components/Dashboard/Dashboard'
import AddTask from './Components/Tasks/Task/AddTask'
import Navbar from './Components/Navbar/Navbar'
import Searchbar from './Components/Searchbar/Searchbar'
import firebase from './Firebase';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.ref = firebase.firestore().collection('tasks')
    this.state = {
      tasks: [],
      searchTerm: ""
    }

    this.handleLikeButton = this.handleLikeButton.bind(this)
    this.handleRemoveButton = this.handleRemoveButton.bind(this)
    this.addTask = this.addTask.bind(this)
    this.handleFilter = this.handleFilter.bind(this)
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    const db = firebase.firestore()
    const allTasks = []
    db.collection('tasks').onSnapshot(collection => {
       const tasks = collection .docs.map(doc => doc.data())
       this.setState({ tasks: tasks, searchTerm: "" })
    })
  }

  handleLikeButton = (task) => (e) => {
    const tasks = [...this.state.tasks]
    const index = tasks.indexOf(task)
    tasks[index].likes++
    this.setState({
      tasks: tasks
    })
  }

  addTask = (taskName) => (e) => {
    this.ref.add({
      id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000000000000),
      title: taskName,
      likes: 0
    })
  }

  handleRemoveButton = (removingTask) => (e) => {
    const tasks = [...this.state.tasks]
    const newTasks = tasks.filter(task => removingTask.id !== task.id)
    this.setState({
      tasks: newTasks
    })
  }


  handleFilter = (searchTerm) => {
    this.setState({
      searchTerm: searchTerm
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Navbar />
        <Searchbar handleFilter={this.handleFilter} />
        <AddTask addTask={this.addTask} />
        <Dashboard tasks={this.state.tasks} searchTerm={this.state.searchTerm} handleLikeButton={this.handleLikeButton} handleRemoveButton={this.handleRemoveButton}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

DASHBOARD.JS -

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Tasks from '../Tasks/Tasks'

class Dashboard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.filterTasks = this.filterTasks.bind(this)
  }

  filterTasks = () => {
      const tasks = [...this.props.tasks]
      const newArray = tasks.filter(task =>
        task.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.props.searchTerm.toLowerCase()) > -1)
      return (
        <Tasks tasks={newArray} handleLikeButton={this.props.handleLikeButton} handleRemoveButton={this.props.handleRemoveButton}  />
      )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Dashboard</h2>
        {this.filterTasks()}
      </div>
    )
  }
}


export default Dashboard
```

ADDTASK.JS

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class AddTask extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      addNewTaskFieldEmpty: true,
      taskName: ""
    }

    this.onChangeHandler = this.onChangeHandler.bind(this)
    this.disableButton = this.disableButton.bind(this)
  }


  onChangeHandler(e) {
    this.setState({
      taskName: e.target.value,
    })
    this.disableButton(e.target.value)
  }

  disableButton(taskName) {
    if(taskName.length == 0) {
      this.setState({addNewTaskFieldEmpty: true})
    } else {
      this.setState({addNewTaskFieldEmpty: false})
    }
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="mdc-text-field half-size">
          <input className="mdc-text-field__input " onChange={this.onChangeHandler}  />
          <div className="mdc-line-ripple"></div>
          <label className="mdc-floating-label">Task Name</label>
        </div>
        <a className={"btn-floating btn-large waves-effect waves-light red " + (this.state.addNewTaskFieldEmpty ? 'disabled' : '')} onClick={this.props.addTask(this.state.taskName)}><i className="material-icons">add</i></a>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default AddTask
```

Comment: What is `this.props.searchTerm`? Where do you define it? Do you mean `this.state.searchTerm`?

Comment: @JackBashford I receive searchTerm from the Searchbar component in APP. I pass this on to the Dashboard component as props and do my search filtering there. So I want to filter the tasks with the searchTerm (received in Dashboard through props) The initial state of the search is an empty string "". Hopefully this makes more sense, thanks!

Comment: maybe that `toLowerCase` of undefined error actually points to `searchTerm` have you check?

Comment: Yes, I removed toLowerCase from both of them and then the next error will be:
Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined

Comment: Off topic but 2 side notes. 1) you use arrow function to define those `handleSth` methods, so all the `.bind(this)` in constructor is unnecessary. 2) `addTask` is not an event handler, it's a factory function that return an event handler. Not sure if you're aware of the difference

Comment: What is task then. Log and checked?

Comment: Actually check inside `filterTasks` what is `this.props.tasks`

Comment: @hackape - Thanks for the comment, I like to have feedback on my code since I'm still learning. I removed the ```bind(this)``` from the constructor and reading about the factory function now. So how would you write addTask? Thanks!

Comment: Need to know how you use `addTask`

Comment: @hackape - if I console.log in filterTasks ```this.props.tasks``` then I get the correct Array with 2 objects

Comment: @hackape - Thanks for your help. I don't really know why and I try to figure out what  I changed but suddenly the filtering works and I don't receive an error. 
I've added my AddTask to the other components.

Comment: So...the problem just disappeared for unknown reason?

Comment: @hackape - Yes, could the reason be that because of a slow internet connection ```filterTasks()``` is been called while there is no tasks yet (because of the loading time from getting the data from Firestore? I think I need to build a check on that function. Guess that is the problem because I try and study this over a 3g phone connection.

Comment: 2 cases will cause you problem. this.props.tasks === `undefined` or `[undefinded]`. Try pinpoint the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

Lint your `App.css` for any errors.

I encountered this message. I traced it to a CSS include:

```
.box-table { border-color:; border: 1px solid #dbdad8; }
```

The missing value of `border-color:` caused `npm run build` to fail.

Interestingly, the same file contained

```
.submenu-button.submenu-opened:after { background:; }
```

which caused no problems at all.